# d3.js not reading Python-generated JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js

I'm using Python to scrape some data from the web before visualizing said data using d3.js. I'm having an issue reading the generated JSON in d3.js.

Python code:

```
course_json_list = []
obj = {u"course_id": course_id, u"prereqs": prereqs}
        course_json_list.append(json.dumps(obj, indent=4))


# setting up JSON output file
json_output = {"nodes": course_json_list,
               "links": None}

with open("course-data.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(json_output, fp=outfile)
```

When I open this code in gVim, I see:
`{"nodes": ["{\n    \"course_id\": \"Course 1\",\n    \"prereqs\": null,\n...`

My d3.js code:

```
var dataset;
d3.json('course-data.json', function(error, json_data) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    dataset = json_data;
    d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
            .data(dataset.nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("p")
            .text(function(d) {
            //When this is return d; it works
                return d["course_id"];
    });
});
```

I've put it into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it returns:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        "{\n    \"course_id\": \"Course 1\", \n    \"prereqs\": null, \n    \"off_w\": null, \n    \"name\": \"Intro\"\n}",
        "{\n    \"course_id\": \"Course 2\", \n ...
```

JSONLint says the JSON is valid, but my d3.js code won't read it.
Is my python generating bad JSON? If so, how do I generate it correctly? Am I referencing the JSON incorrectly in d3.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though JSONLint says that the code is "valid", I don't think that is the encoding you were aiming for, i.e. a flat list under the `nodes` key.

You are `dump`-ing JSON too often and causing double serialization.

Instead of `course_json_list.append(json.dumps(obj, indent=4))`, you probably only need `course_json_list.append(obj)`. In your case, you are saving strings in `course_json_list` which is getting dumped as a string. In the latter version, you are storing the objects recursively and then relying on the final `json.dump` to take care of serializing the object recursively.